# How do I get latest tweets for specific hashtags or specific words?

Tags: twitter

Is there a software (a Web app or for Windows 8) I can use to subscribe to latest tweets regarding specific hashtags or specific accounts?

For example I want to follow anything happening with "#php" and other keywords. How do people do that, what program does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tweetdeck](https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck) does exactly that. You can subscribe to accounts, or you can have live searches running (a hashtags is technically not different from an ordinary search term).

[image]

You can do this across multiple accounts, and you can filter the streams:

[image]